# start "cvlc" in background on booting without user login

Tags: boot, vlc

I have a command I want to start a webcam to start to stream using vlc /cvlc on/after boot.

The command is:

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=mp2v :input-slave=alsa://hw:CARD=U0x46d0x825,DEV=0 :live-caching=500 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,fps=30,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=1,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:rtp{mux=ts,sdp=rtsp://:8888/live.sdp}'
```

So my question what is the right way to do it?
Please note:

- Should be run in background
- No user login should be required
- Vlc cannot run from "root" user

thank you very much!

Comment: "the right way to do it" depends on what "it" actually is which is unclear. The best approach would probably be to write a systemd service but this is generic Linux - not Pi specific. I would suggest you first work how to do "it" from the command line before attempting to start on boot.